# How can I find the angular coefficient of a segment in a 3D coordinate system?

Tags: 3d, geometry

Given 2 points A(x1,y1,z1) and B(x2,y2,z2), what is the equation to calculate their angular coefficient?

I wish a quite simple equation like this one:

m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

used to calculate the angular coefficient into a cartesian system.

Comment: If you are looking for a single number... that will not properly describe anything in 3D. If you are looking for something more than a single number... what is it that you are looking for?

Comment: It's related to this question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783387/how-can-i-find-a-point-placed-between-2-points-forming-a-segment-using-only-the-p

Answer (score 3):

The term "angular coefficient" doesn't exist in mathematics - You need to be more explicit about exactly what it is you want to find out about these 2 points.

The equation you have descibred for 2D systems is the gradient - the change in Y with respect to the change in X.  The equivalent concept in 3 dimensions would be the change in Y with respect to X, and the change in Z with respect to X, i.e. 2 values - the gradient of Y and Z respectively with respect to X:

```
(y2 - y1) /  (x2 - x1)
```

and

```
(z2 - z1) / (x2 - x1)
```

However I get the impression this isnt what you are after - what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, now I suppose this double solution it will make me the things more complex :P. Sorry if I translated literally the Italian "coefficiente angolare" without checking the right form, anyway you catch it  :)

Comment: Nice touch, Justin: when you have more than one independent variable and one asks you to compute the slope ("coeficiente angular" for me, a Brazilian) you have to ask "in which direction?" - that's why the gradient is a vector, not a scalar. The thing is most people do not relate the slope of a linear function with the notion of derivative and thus get lost with a question that should be simple to answer: what is the slope of a multivariate linear function?

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia, "coefficiente angolare" is "slope" in English. Maybe you want to know the slope of the line?  In any number of dimensions, the definition "rise / run" can still work.  In 3D, rise is the Z difference and run is the length of the segment projected onto the Z plane:

m = (z2 - z1) / sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )