# How can I find a point placed between 2 points forming a segment using only the partial length of the segment?

Tags: 3d, geometry

Given 2 points A(x0,y0,z0) and C(x2,y2,z2) forming a segment of length "k", what is the equation to find a point C(x1,y1,z1) placed at "k-1" distance from A?

Comment: Do you want an equation or an algorithm / computer program? If you just want an equation then it's not really programming related.

Comment: I need an equation like this one used for 2D:

d^2 = (x-k)^2 + (y-q-mk)^2

where "d" is the known distance, "x" and "y" known coordinates, "m" the gradient, and "q" the "y-intercept"

Comment: The above equation is determined by the following used on a 2D plane: 

Point B(k, m*k+q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic maths. If you already have classes handling vectors and points, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Vector direction = C - A;
direction.Normalize();
Point newpoint = A + (k-1) * direction;
```

You just need

- difference between points (gives a vector)
- scalar product of a float with a vector (gives a new vector)
- addition of a point and a vector (gives a new point)

Comment: Great explanation! I learned the right way and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Smells like homework, so, general idea, but no code:

Get the slope of AC for each coordinate set (x, y, and z).  Then progress k-1 units from A at each of the calculated slope to get the coordinates of the new point.

Comment: No homeworks, game :P

Pratically I have a routine sending only the distance at which some objects are, every object has a common origin and a known target