# Find limiting point between 2 points

Tags: c#, vector, xna

- I have the coordinate of point A and another point (like B, C or D).
- I also have the distance between A and the other point.
- I know the maximum allowed distance between A and the other point (illustrated with the purple line and the imaginary circle).
- Question: How do I find the coordinates of the red points (B1 or C1 or D1).
- Example: **A=(-1,1), E=(3,-8)**, Max allowed distance = 4. What is the coordinate of point E1?

Here is an image of the problem:
[image: problem]

Note:
I found 2 other questions that are pretty similar or equal but I'm not able to work it out with those:
[Finding coordinates of a point between two points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886092/finding-coordinates-of-a-point-between-two-points)

[How can I find a point placed between 2 points forming a segment using only the partial length of the segment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783387/how-can-i-find-a-point-placed-between-2-points-forming-a-segment-using-only-the)

P.S. This is not homework I need this for a programming problem but I forgot my Maths...

Comment: Is this really a programming problem? It seems to be more a base-math problem

Comment: So, you want a vector in the direction A -> B/C/D, of length MaxDistance?

Comment: Xanatos: Yes it's a programming problem because this is the problem I'm having for setting a rally point for a game in C#/XNA.

Comment: George: No I don't want the vector (like a vector) but I need just the coordinate of the point on the line between A->B for example where the exact location of the point is LIMITED (not determined) by a maximum range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming A is a position vector, B is a position vector, and maxLength is the max length you're allowing for.

`A` and `B` are [`Vector2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx)'s (as you tagged this question [xna](/questions/tagged/xna)).

```
// Create a vector that describes going from A to B
var AtoB = (B - A);
// Make a vector going from A to B, but only one unit in length
var AtoBUnitLength = Vector2.Normalize(AtoB);
// Make a vector in the direction of B from A, of length maxLength
var AtoB1 = AtoBUnitLength * maxLength;
// B1 is the starting point (A) + the direction vector of the
// correct length we just created.
var B1 = A + AtoB1;

// One liner:
var B1 = A + Vector2.Normalize(B - A) * maxLength;
```

Comment: Yes the coordinates are indeed Vector2 structs. And this solution works perfectly and doesn't seem to cost much performance either. Just note that Normalize() returns void so it still requires 2-3 lines but nevertheless it works.

Comment: @user653160: Corrected to use the static `Normalize` method.